# Sticky text when scrolling down

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hi good people of stackoverflow,

I am stuck with the sticky header. I found the way on how to do it on [W3school](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_sticky_header), however when I implement it into my html/js/css file it doesn't work.

In short the text *Name Surname* should stick on top of the browser window when scrolling down. 
I have tried many things like putting the js code inside script tags, changing the function name and call it as first thing in body and so on. Non of it brought expected results.

Here is the code:

```js
function scroll() {
  myFunction()
};

var header = document.getElementById("home-name");
var sticky = header.offsetTop;

function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
    header.classList.add("sticky");
  } else {
    header.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}

var nav = false;

function openSideMenu(){
    document.getElementById('side-menu').style.width = '250px';
    //document.getElementById('main').style.marginLeft = '250px';
    nav = true;
}

function closeSideMenu(){
    document.getElementById('side-menu').style.width = '60px';
    //document.getElementById('main').style.marginLeft = '60px';
    nav = false;
}

function toCross(x){
    x.classList.toggle("change");
    nav ? closeSideMenu() : openSideMenu();
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Arial", Serif;
  margin: 0;
  /*without margin = 0 image would have small margin*/
  background-color: white;
}


/*.background-home, .background-gallery, .background-contact {
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    position: relative;
}

.background-home{
    background-image: url("/mnt/120AA1F00AA1D0D1/Editing/Wedding wedpage/obrazki/22343878_10210125005464505_1420779932_o.jpg");
    background-position: center -900px;
    min-height: 100vh;
}

.background-gallery {
    background-image: url("/mnt/120AA1F00AA1D0D1/Programming/Wedding-Web-Page/pictures/white_background.png");
    background-position: center;
    min-height: 100vh;
    background-size: cover;
}

/*.background-contact {
    background-image: url("/mnt/120AA1F00AA1D0D1/Editing/Wedding wedpage/obrazki/21167099_10209868968863750_7278329271954592356_o.jpg");
    background-position: center;
    height: 100vh;
}*/

.bar1,
.bar2,
.bar3 {
  width: 35px;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: #333;
  margin: 6px;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.open-menu a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px 5px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  font-size: 17px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.open-menu a:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
  color: #000;
}

.change .bar1 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
}

.change .bar2 {
  opacity: 0;
}

.change .bar3 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
}

.side-nav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 60px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: white;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  /*hides overflow text in side menu*/
  padding-top: 60px;
  transition: 0.1s;
}

.side-nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 14px;
}

.side-nav a {
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 0px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: black;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: 0.1s;
}

.side-nav li:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

div#side-menu li {
  background-position: left;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

div#side-menu li#youtube {
  background-image: url("/mnt/120AA1F00AA1D0D1/Programming/Wedding-Web-Page/pictures/youtube32.png");
}

div.list-margin {
  padding-left: 50px;
}

.quote {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 12px;
  font-family: "Dancing Script";
  font-size: 60px;
  color: white;
}

.title {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  font-size: 120px;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: 'Amatic SC', cursive;
}

#home-name {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 5%;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: black;
  z-index: 1;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Bellefair', serif;
}

#home-name:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  margin-left: -150px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 1px;
}

.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.sticky+.content {
  padding-top: 102px;
}

#titleGallery {
  top: 100%;
  font-family: 'Amatic SC', cursive;
}

#Terka-A-Jakub-Video {
  position: absolute;
  top: 150%;
  left: 10%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>Wedding Page</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="style.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dancing+Script:700">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Amatic+SC" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bellefair" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="main.js"></script>

</head>

<body onscroll="scroll();">

  <div class="header" id="home-name">
    <p>Name&nbsp;Surname</p>
  </div>
  <div class="background-home"></div>
  <div class="background-gallery"></div>
  <div class="background-contact"></div>

  <div id="side-menu" class="side-nav">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <div class="list-margin">Home</div>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li id="youtube">
        <a href="#">
          <div class="list-margin">Gallery</div>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <div class="list-margin">Get&nbsp;in&nbsp;Touch</div>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <div class="list-margin">About&nbsp;Me</div>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <div class="list-margin">Contact</div>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div>
    <span class="open-menu">
            <a href="#" onclick="toCross(this)">
                <div class="bar1"></div>
                <div class="bar2"></div>
                <div class="bar3"></div>
            </a>
        </span>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <p class="quote">One video, <br> thousands memories.</p>
    <iframe id="Terka-A-Jakub-Video" width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/xY2uUyFyNh4?rel=0" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    <p class="title" id="titleGallery">Gallery</p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

As always, any help will be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Your class is not overriding the original properties of the element. Use important sample is as follows:

```
.sticky {
    position: fixed !important;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
 };
```

```js
var header = document.getElementById("home-name");
var sticky = header.offsetTop;
function scroll() {
  myFunction()
};



function myFunction() {
console.log(window.pageYOffset >= sticky)
  if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
    header.classList.add("sticky");
  } else {
    header.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}

var nav = false;

function openSideMenu(){
    document.getElementById('side-menu').style.width = '250px';
    //document.getElementById('main').style.marginLeft = '250px';
    nav = true;
}

function closeSideMenu(){
    document.getElementById('side-menu').style.width = '60px';
    //document.getElementById('main').style.marginLeft = '60px';
    nav = false;
}

function toCross(x){
    x.classList.toggle("change");
    nav ? closeSideMenu() : openSideMenu();
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Arial", Serif;
  margin: 0;
  /*without margin = 0 image would have small margin*/
  background-color: white;
}


/*.background-home, .background-gallery, .background-contact {
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    position: relative;
}

.background-home{
    background-image: url("/mnt/120AA1F00AA1D0D1/Editing/Wedding wedpage/obrazki/22343878_10210125005464505_1420779932_o.jpg");
    background-position: center -900px;
    min-height: 100vh;
}

.background-gallery {
    background-image: url("/mnt/120AA1F00AA1D0D1/Programming/Wedding-Web-Page/pictures/white_background.png");
    background-position: center;
    min-height: 100vh;
    background-size: cover;
}

/*.background-contact {
    background-image: url("/mnt/120AA1F00AA1D0D1/Editing/Wedding wedpage/obrazki/21167099_10209868968863750_7278329271954592356_o.jpg");
    background-position: center;
    height: 100vh;
}*/

.bar1,
.bar2,
.bar3 {
  width: 35px;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: #333;
  margin: 6px;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.open-menu a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px 5px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  font-size: 17px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.open-menu a:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
  color: #000;
}

.change .bar1 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
}

.change .bar2 {
  opacity: 0;
}

.change .bar3 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
}

.side-nav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 60px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: white;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  /*hides overflow text in side menu*/
  padding-top: 60px;
  transition: 0.1s;
  display:none;
}

.side-nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 14px;
}

.side-nav a {
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 0px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: black;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: 0.1s;
}

.side-nav li:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

div#side-menu li {
  background-position: left;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

div#side-menu li#youtube {
  background-image: url("/mnt/120AA1F00AA1D0D1/Programming/Wedding-Web-Page/pictures/youtube32.png");
}

div.list-margin {
  padding-left: 50px;
}

.quote {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 12px;
  font-family: "Dancing Script";
  font-size: 60px;
  color: white;
}

.title {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  font-size: 120px;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: 'Amatic SC', cursive;
}

#home-name {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 5%;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: black;
  z-index: 1;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Bellefair', serif;
}

#home-name:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  margin-left: -150px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 1px;
}

.sticky {
  position: fixed !important;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.sticky+.content {
  padding-top: 102px;
}

#titleGallery {
  top: 100%;
  font-family: 'Amatic SC', cursive;
}

#Terka-A-Jakub-Video {
  position: absolute;
  top: 150%;
  left: 10%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>Wedding Page</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="style.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dancing+Script:700">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Amatic+SC" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bellefair" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="main.js"></script>

</head>

<body onscroll="scroll();">

  <div class="header" id="home-name">
    <p>Name&nbsp;Surname</p>
  </div>
  <div class="background-home"></div>
  <div class="background-gallery"></div>
  <div class="background-contact"></div>

  <div id="side-menu" class="side-nav">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <div class="list-margin">Home</div>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li id="youtube">
        <a href="#">
          <div class="list-margin">Gallery</div>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <div class="list-margin">Get&nbsp;in&nbsp;Touch</div>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <div class="list-margin">About&nbsp;Me</div>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <div class="list-margin">Contact</div>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div>
    <span class="open-menu">
            <a href="#" onclick="toCross(this)">
                <div class="bar1"></div>
                <div class="bar2"></div>
                <div class="bar3"></div>
            </a>
        </span>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <p class="quote">One video, <br> thousands memories.</p>
    <iframe id="Terka-A-Jakub-Video" width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/xY2uUyFyNh4?rel=0" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    <p class="title" id="titleGallery">Gallery</p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I have checked with your code was working for me without the condition which you have utilizing for offset top the condition was retiring always true. Let me have look once again. While the time can you clear the cache of the page and rerun the code.

Comment: Move `<script src="main.js"></script>` from <head> before </body>